# Why are some google snippet results bold?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, search-results

[image: Featured Snippet Questions]

Recently, when I search for keyword **"best mlm software"** I got a featured snippet having "List of Multi Level Marketing Software". I noted that two of list's item were **BOLD** text. Didn't know why??? Can anyone explain to me why these two were words are **BOLD** even though the first item didn't have any word related to my keyword "best mlm software"..????

Just curious to know...!!

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about your own website.

Answer (score 1):

Those are search results, based on your personalization. My personalized SERP looks like:

[image]
You see, another terms are bolded.
And, if you do a kind of non-personalized search, i.e. with an incognito tab, so the SERP has even no featured answer, and no bolded terms, like on:

[image]

Comment: Hello @evgeniy, I was already searching it from private mode of Mozilla Firefox.